# proof that the square of any odd number, decreased by one, is divisible by 4

Tags: analysis

I want to proof that the square of any odd number, decreased by one, is divisible by $4$. I got the following formula:

$$
\frac{(2n-1)^2-1}{4} = y
$$

I want to show that y is a natural number. After further evaluation I get:

$$
n^2-n = y
$$

Which means that y is a natural number. So the statement is true. It his correct?

Furthermore I should conclude from this that the following equation with integers $x$ and $y$ is unsolvable:

$$
x^2-y^2 = 1002
$$

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Your first demonstration looks correct.  As for the second, it should really be posed as a separate question, not joined here, but it can be approached by factoring $x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$.  Then observe that $1002 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 167$.  Since $1002$ has only the one factor of $2$, it cannot be written as $a \cdot b$ where $a$ and $b$ are either both even or both odd, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = n^2-n$ is indeed an integer and your proof is correct!

$1002$ is an even number. So $x$ and $y$ are both even or both odd.

If $x$ and $y$ are both even, we can write $x = 2a$ and $y = 2b$. So $1002 = x^2 - y^2 = 4a^2 - 4b^2 = 4(a^2-b^2)$.

If $x$ and $y$ are both odd, $x^2-1$ and $y^2-1$ are divisible by 4 (you have already proved that). So $(x^2-1) - (y^2-1) = x^2 - y^2 = 1002$ should also be divisible by 4.

In both cases a solution would imply that 1002 is divisible by 4, which isn't the case. So the equation can't have any solutions.

Answer (score 2):

For the first, yes, you are right.

For the second, note that $$m^2\equiv 0\ \ \text{or}\ \ 1\pmod 4$$for every integer $m$, and that
$$1002\equiv 2\pmod 4$$